# C++ function pointer as Template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-signature

I have questions with below code snippet, not sure if I correctly understand the codes.

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                     
class RunnableAdapter<R(*)(Args...)> {
 public:
  typedef R (RunType)(Args...);

  explicit RunnableAdapter(R(*function)(Args...))   
      : function_(function) {
  }

  R Run(Arg... args) {
    return function_(args...);
  }

 private:
  R (*function_)(Args...);
};
```

1. `<R(*)(Args...)>` is a "type of function pointer"and blink space  between R and (*) is not necessarily required?
2. and what could instanciation of RunnableAdapter be?
   I assume it is like below.
   `void myFunction(int i){  //   };
    RunnableAdfapter<(void)(*)(int)> ra(MyFunction);
    ra.Run(1);    //which calls MyFunction(1)`

Answer (score 1):

At first the code you provided have some mistakes and does not even compile. To answer tou questions:

1. Spaces are not necessary.
2. See below example

You could declare you class like this

```
template <typename T>
class RunnableAdapter;

template <typename R, typename... Args>                                     
class RunnableAdapter<R(*)(Args...)> { ... }
```

And instantiate it

```
RunnableAdapter<void(*)(int)> ra(&myFunction);
```

But you could simplify it (here is full working example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class RunnableAdapter;

template <typename R, typename... Args>                                     
class RunnableAdapter<R (Args...)> {
public:

  explicit RunnableAdapter(R(*function)(Args...))   
      : function_(function) {
  }

  R Run(Args... args) {
    return function_(args...);
  }

private:
  R (*function_)(Args...);
};

void myFunction(int i){ std::cout << i << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    RunnableAdapter<void(int)> ra(&myFunction);
    ra.Run(1);
}
```

This would allow instantiation with signature-like expressions  like `void(int)`.
It just looks better, no need in `(*)`.

Also here is another way is to do it without class specialization, like this. 
The result is the same, but class declaration and instantiation is slightly different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename R, typename... Args>                                     
class RunnableAdapter {
public:

  explicit RunnableAdapter(R(*function)(Args...))   
      : function_(function) {
  }

  R Run(Args... args) {
    return function_(args...);
  }

private:
  R (*function_)(Args...);
};

void myFunction(int i){ std::cout << i << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    RunnableAdapter<void, int> ra(&myFunction);
    ra.Run(1);
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Jarod42 proposed it is better to make `Run` like this

```
template<typename... Ts>
R Run(Ts&&... args) {
  return function_(std::forward<Ts...>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Run should be written `template <typename ...Ts>R Run(Ts&&... args) {
    return function_(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }` (to handle function which transfers `unique_ptr` ownership, for example).

Comment: @Jarod42 does it need another template `template <typename ...Ts>`? What is the difference from `R Run(Args&&... args) { return function_(std::forward<Args...>(args)...); }`? However good comment, I will update my answer.

Comment: With `Ts&&` you have forward reference (`Ts` is deduced from function call). `Args&&` are fixed by class and would be reference (r-value or l-value reference depending of `Args` and collapsing rules).

Comment: Thanks! guys and sorry for not fully working code. I jsut tired to study part of open source. now it makes more sense to me.  it is way better neat without (*) though, original source just has it. it made me more confused. and original code had wrapping code for function parameters as well. :)

Comment: now I got understood why specialized `RunnableAdapter<R(*)(Args...)> `is needed. since it should be differenctiated from `RunnableAdapter<R(T::*)(Args...)>`. so have different RunType each for function and method binding.